# d.py number of bans in a guild

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I tried using `embed.add_field(name="Ban Count", value=f"{len(await ctx.guild.bans())} Bans",inline=False)`
but I get this error `object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression`   How do I display the amount of bans?

Comment: Use the `len()` function to get the number of bans `ban_count = len(ctx.guild.bans())`, then Use the result in your code, `embed.add_field(name="Ban Count", value=f"{ban_count} Bans", inline=False)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first convert the bans into a list, then get the length of the list:

```py
bans_list = [entry async for entry in ctx.guild.bans()]
number_of_bans = len(bans_list)

# output number of bans, etc...
```